# JoptionPane using for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, joptionpane

Please Help me with following problem.

I have this program and I have to print out everything in just one JOptionPane message dialog box. Can anyone help me? Here's the code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {


       for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: Uhh...what's the problem...?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180567/joptionpane-display-

Comment: That code is running  and counting 0 to 12  one by one by just pressing ok .   What i am trying to do is I want to print them all in just one dialog box . without pressing ok to count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have a for loop and you want to keep on printing the text from the for loop in your JOption pane...And you want to display ALL of the text:**

To do this, you can use StringBuilder, and the `append` method.

```
StringBuilder LOLOL= new StringBuilder();
buff.append( "ADD THIS" ).append("\n");
```

So now, all of the strings will be together.